# eventTicket PassBook relevant without a relevant location not work in iOS7

Tags: ios, passbook

I make a passBook with type eventTicket ,just relevant with date，there is no locations.It works well in iOS6 ,but not shown in iOS7.Documents says that:Relevant if the date and any location matches.Without a relevant location, relevant if the date matches. So it should support relevantDate ,I want to know why not work in iOS7.  When I add locations in ,it shows on the locked screen in iOS7.Who can tell me why?Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a link to the pass - could be a time zone issue.  If the pass is valid then you may well have found a bug and your best bet would be to file a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) and post in the the [Passbook Topic on the Apple developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/connected/passbook).

Comment: I try the date for Boardingcard and can be use in iOS7.So it should not be time zone issue.I made a bug report.Thank you @PassKit